# Sails object not available in log.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, sails.js

Im building a custom logger using Winston in Sails. I would like to set a log level variable in all of my various environment configs and reference that variable in the `log.js` file. This seems to work in my controllers with a reference of `sails.config.variableName` but the same reference in `log.js` throws: `Details:ReferenceError: sails is not defined` Can someone tell me how to reference this variable from the config? Is there some sort of require statement that I can add?

I would rather **not** set the level with some sort of switch/conditional that references the env variable used to start up the application in the `log.js` (ie. `process.env.myEnvironment`)

Comment: Can you post an example of your log.js code so far? If you haven't seen it already, here's a helpful Sails doc on [using custom loggers and their configuration in sails](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-log#?using-a-custom-logger).

Comment: Yep, I am using those docs. So where you see:
```module.exports.log = {
  // Pass in our custom logger, and pass all log levels through.
  custom: customLogger,
  level: 'silly',

  // Disable captain's log so it doesn't prefix or stringify our meta data.
  inspect: false
};```

I want to have `level: sails.config.logLevel`

Comment: Need any help, got a repo? I need this too :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the repo. From what I have found so far, I don't think this is possible. It seems to all be in sails's hands and that object doesn't seem to be loaded before the env files are.

Comment: What version of Sails are you using? Have you tried this variable in your [sails.config.globals](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-globals)? Also, you can test this out in the [sails.config.log](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-log) for log configuration alone.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this, even though you may not like it, would be to pass it in as an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE to Sails at startup instead of using the env/{name}.js files. log.js loads before the full Sails object and you can't reference it. I recommend using:

```
process.env.{your variable name}
ex: process.env.LOG_LEVEL
```

Where logLevel is passed to the sails.js app at startup using:

```
>> LOG_LEVEL=info NODE_ENV=dev node app.js
```

In this scenario both LOG_LEVEL and NODE_ENV are available to you in the log.js file.

But it's not a "switch" as much as it's an environment specific setting. Externalizing environment specific entities is actually a common practice and recommended for cloud environments where you can alter the values without having to redeploy code.

When running in containers you can easily change the log level from DEBUG to INFO and cycle your containers without redeploying your code. You then switch it back the same way without any downtime.